# XML over HTTP with GZIP - Bandwidth efficiency

Tags: xml, gzip, bandwidth

In one of my applications, I need to download about 50,000 XML documents, most averaging around 5kb in size. I need to find the most efficient way bandwidth wise to transfer all of it over http, and the XML is gzipped. Which is the most efficient way to download it, using the least bandwidth. Downloading each XML file individually, downloading them in sets, or are they practically the same? I have no idea as I  don't really know how GZIP would effect this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using HTTP, the primary factor for perceived connection speed is the number of TCP connections established.

Serving it as one master file will help (for only one connection would be established). If the server, supports [`Accept-Ranges`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-105) (in other words, the resumption of file downloads) feature, then you can use a 'smarter' client to download the master file in chunks over several connections, and regroup them.

But, if that cannot be done, use a HTTP client that supports HTTP 1.1 Keep-alive. That way, the connection would be re-used over several files.

Comment: Thanks, but I am worrying more about bandwidth efficiency, not speed. I am actually running this on App Engine, so long running requests and keep alive won't work too well.

Comment: Well, if you have already employed GZIP, then you cannot expect to gain any more in bandwidth efficiency.

Comment: As in, multiple seperate xml files gzipped will be the same size as combined xml files when gzipped?

Comment: Yes, more or less. Unless you want to save bandwidth on the HTTP response headers (which would run into bytes).

Comment: @Ricky, glad to be help. There's one point I haven't been more specific about. You might want to perform a size comparison test between 50k GZIP files, and a master GZIP file (with 50k files). If the difference is more than a few kilobytes, you should choose the better option.

Answer (score 0):

I found another type of encoding that might be better than GZIP for XML over HTTP, it's called [EXI](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-parameters/http-parameters.xml) (Efficient XML Interchange). It's currently implemented for Apache web server and probably other web servers will adopt it. [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/exi-evaluation/#compactness-results) is a benchmark comparing it to GZIP.